# What does expand method signify in beam?

Tags: apache-beam

Is expand like a template that expands to a directed acyclic graph? DoFn seems like something that runs on an individual task or process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically allows for refactoring and re-using code throughout your pipeline.

You can combine several pipeline steps (including DoFn if you wish so) in a `PTransform` (see [official WordCount Example](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/#creating-composite-transforms) from beam and [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#composite-transform-creation), where they actually use `expand`) which simplifies unit testing, naming and makes for an overall cleaner DAG. The latter can be seen in the following screenshot, which I stole from the official Dataflow documentation page [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-monitoring-intf#composite-transforms) (<- in this link they also show the corresponding Python and Java Code)

[image]